# Simple error checking if statement

Tags: php, exception, try-catch, custom-errors

I want to replace the list of `warning`s and `error`s with a simple error banner. I'm trying to check if this code produce errors and if so output a custom error

```
$sxml = simplexml_load_file($yurl)
```

I played around with the `try` `catch` block but I just can't seem to get it right, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`libxml_use_internal_errors()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php)

```
<?php

    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

    $sxml = simplexml_load_file($yurl);

    if (!$sxml) {
        foreach (libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
            // Custom error banner here
                switch ($error->level) {
                    case LIBXML_ERR_WARNING:
                        $return .= "Warning $error->code: ";
                        break;
                    case LIBXML_ERR_ERROR:
                        $return .= "Error $error->code: ";
                        break;
                    case LIBXML_ERR_FATAL:
                        $return .= "Fatal Error $error->code: ";
                        break;
                    }    
        }
            //clears libxml error buffer
        libxml_clear_errors();
    }

?>
```

[`libxml_get_errors()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-get-errors.php) returns an array of [`libXMLError`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.libxmlerror.php) objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can only `catch` exceptions, not errors.

Use [`set_error_handler()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) to replace PHP's default error handler with your own function.